# iReport - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception, ireport

Im using iReport 3.7.6.

I have a Parameter with following parameter class: `at.gv.domain.print.impl.ParameterClass`.

For using that class I did following:

--> Extras --> Option --> Classpath --> Add Folder -->

```
C:\Development\Projectname\workspace\DomainProject\target\classes
```

Under `C:\Development\Projectname\workspace\DomainProject\target\classes\at\gv\domain\print\impl` there are my `ParameterClass.class`.

Now if I wanna compile the `.jrxml` I get following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :

1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.gv.domain.print.impl.ParameterClass
```

Someone can tell me why? I added the classpath entry so why the class got not found?

I tried to make a `.jar` of my Domain project - if I added that the class got found. Is there any problem with target directory (Im using Maven)?

Comment: A directory should be ok, not something to do with spaces in the path or a path being longer that 256 chars?  But if you are using maven why not just use the jar it generates (assuming it is a jar project)

Comment: Thanks for the response! There are no spaces in the path and the path isnt longer than 256chars. The reason why I dont want to generate a JAR is because Im in developing state and if I change the domain class I always have to create a JAR file and after that I can change the .jrxml - thats not fast, if I use the folder Im always up to date. Furthermore there are more than 1 project (its a EAR)! A year ago I used iReport 3.0.0 and I did the same for another project and all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Your probleme is with the jar of ireport, I think that the version of ireport is not the same as the jar used in the IDE, if it's true try to change the jar that's all, hope this help.